# Error deploying code with AWS CDK CLI using command "npx cdk deploy"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli, aws-cdk

I'm aiming to build OCPP compliant software for ev networks. I'm very interested in using AWS solutions for this task. I'm following along with the solution walkthrough posted in this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/building-an-ocpp-compliant-electric-vehicle-charge-point-operator-solution-using-aws-iot-core/However when I go to deploy the code with "npx cdk deploy" I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to bundle asset AwsOcppGatewayStack/OCPPMessageProcessor/Code/Stage, bundle output is located at C:\Users\amina\aws-ocpp-gateway\cdk.out\asset.a92310394f39f53768bf82a87adcaf43a1501f30e8528869497b26e50660fbd0-error: Error: docker exited with status 1
--> Command: docker run --rm -u "1000:1000" -v "C:\\Users\\amina\\aws-ocpp-gateway\\src\\ocpp-message-processor:/asset-input:delegated" -v "C:\\Users\\amina\\aws-ocpp-gateway\\cdk.out\\asset.a92310394f39f53768bf82a87adcaf43a1501f30e8528869497b26e50660fbd0:/asset-output:delegated" -w "/asset-input" "public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.9" bash -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output && cp -au . /asset-output"
at AssetStaging.bundle (C:\Users\amina\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\core\lib\asset-staging.ts:468:13)
at AssetStaging.stageByBundling (C:\Users\amina\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\core\lib\asset-staging.ts:331:10)
at stageThisAsset (C:\Users\amina\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\core\lib\asset-staging.ts:197:35)
at Cache.obtain (C:\Users\amina\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\core\lib\private\cache.ts:24:13)
at new AssetStaging (C:\Users\amina\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\core\lib\asset-staging.ts:222:44)
at new Asset (C:\Users\amina\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-s3-assets\lib\asset.ts:128:21)
at AssetCode.bind (C:\Users\amina\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-lambda\lib\code.ts:278:20)
at new Function (C:\Users\amina\aws-ocpp-gateway\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-lambda\lib\function.ts:726:29)
at new AwsOcppGatewayStack (C:\Users\amina\aws-ocpp-gateway\lib\aws-ocpp-gateway-stack.ts:494:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\amina\aws-ocpp-gateway\bin\aws-ocpp-gateway.ts:8:1)
```

Does anyone know of a fix for this

I tried using the AWS CDK CLI tools for this and expected it to show up in my cloud formation stacks but it doesn't, instead I get the above error. I also get an error when i try bootstraping saying that no credentials have been configured for my AWS account.